# how to have a different page from the front page?

Tags: blocks

In my site, all my pages are the same as the front page. For example, I have our team block and price table on the front page, but I also see them in blog posts or article pages.

Why is this happening? How do I have a different page from the front page?

Answer (score 1):

When placing the block, you can set the block visibility conditions.

To get a block to show up only on the home page, you would set `<front>` and `Show for the listed pages` under the pages visibility section.

Comment: Thank you very much